# Help Installing a custom ROM

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery

Hi I need some help with this,I want to install a custom rom to my Samsung galaxy s4 mini (I9190), I already know what rom is, and how that works, but  I don't know how to install it on any device, I don't have custom recovery also. So if some one could guide me step by step, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Begin by rooting (if you didnt already). Then using whatever custom recovery you chose to install, you can install the ROM. Search around for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a custom recovery like CWM or TWRP try this link 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2398143
After you have installed a custom recovery boot into that recovery (usually it's by pressing home, power and volume up buttons simultaneously, leave the volume up button as soon as you see Samsung logo)
Make a backup of current Rom for safety. 
Then choose apply update from sdcard navigate to the custom Rom file and flash it. And wait for some mins. 
You will be in the new Rom :)

Answer (score 0):

Use apps like **flashify** from play store on your own risk! Flashing custom rom without custom recovery is risky business! Custom recovery helps you to take **nandroid backup**.